# How to get rid of margins of persp() plot?

Tags: r, plot

No matter what I try to do, I cannot get rid of the right and left margins. In my opinion, the following code (MWE) should do what I expect:

```
library("raster")
r <- raster(extent(0,5,0,10), res=1)
r[] <- runif(ncell(r))
pdf("r.pdf",5,7.5, colormodel = "cmyk")
par(fin=c(5,7.5))
par(mai=rep(0,4))
par(omi=rep(0,4))
persp(r, box=TRUE, axes=FALSE, scale=FALSE, col="gray", theta=250,
      phi=15, ltheta=90, lphi=45, shade=0.7, border=NA,fin=c(5,7.5))
dev.off()
```

Instead it gives this result:
[image: margins persp]

The `par(mai=rep(0,4))` works with any other plot, but not the ones created with `persp`. The thing is that I want the width of the figure itself to be exactly 5 inches. Any suggestions?

Comment: yes, `xaxs = "i"` did the trick. Thank you! This should be an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `xaxs = "i"` to your `persp` call.

It's documented on the `?par` help page.  The default setting is `xaxs = "r"`, which "...extends the data range by 4 percent at each end..."  Setting `xaxs = "i"` prevents extending the data range.